# How to connect to WiFi when windows 10 bug is not showing access points

Tags: windows-10

My Network (WiFi) icon suddenly stopped getting shown on taskbar of Windows 10. I tried multiple posts on internet to get it enabled. But nothing worked. Till Windows provides a fix how can I connect to WiFi?

Answer (score 1):

Connect to the WiFi access point on your mobile phone and make a note of WiFi access point name, security type and WiFi password.

Goto "Control Panel" and choose "Network and Sharing Center". Click on "Set up a new connection or network". Then choose "Manually connect to a wireless network" on the popup and choose Next button. Fill the WiFi access point name in "Network name", "Security type"(Most personal WiFi routers use "WPA2-Personal"), "Encryption type" and "Security key" (password) which were noted from mobile phone in above first step. Enable checkbox "Start this connection automatically". It is optional to enable checkbox of "Connect even if network is not broadcasting". Now choose Next button. Your laptop should now successfully connect to WiFi.

Second solution is to upgrade your windows 10 to version 2004. Post this upgrade the wifi/network icon started appearing for me. This confirms it was a bug in previous version of Windows 10 (1903)

Answer (score 0):

Open the Network Control Panel.

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type `net`.
- Click on the *Network* gear icon.
- Select *Wi-Fi*.
- Click on *Show available networks*.
- Pick one and connect.

[image: Network Wi-Fi CPL]

You might also use a tool such as Nirsoft's free [WiFi Info View](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wifi_information_view.html) to view signal strength, channel and other details, as well as to find the SSID (name) of the network (unless the name is hidden).

[image: Nirsoft's WiFi Info View]